# Chess algorithm transposition tables

Tags: hashtable, chess

I'm in the middle of creating chess algorithm. I found out that transposition tables may improve algorithm's speed, but it looks weird.

I create table for positions on 4th depth and on this level I compare positions with this table. If table has this posiotn I get the value of this position and skip this node. If I don't find this position I count the score for it going deeper and add this position to table. It improves my algorithm for every position. For example from 577576 searched leaves to 425310. When I do the same for 5th depth it increases the number of searched leaves.

Is it possible that using transpositions tables increase the number of searched leaves?

Comment: This question is way too broad and extremely thin on details. We don't have a crystal ball, we can only comment on code you can show that we can understand.

Comment: @melpomene It seems to be "Help I need to make a chess algorithm" which as you point out isn't really a question at all.

Comment: If you use an Alpha Beta algorithm and use a Transposition entry for example of depth 5 for a node at depth 3 then it ist theoretically possible to search through more nodes. I had a similiar problem but i am Not sure If that was the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

A good chess engine should always use a transposition table. Your table key should have the depth as it's parameter. You shouldn't need to allocate a table for each depth.

TT table will most likely increase your search speed.